# Why can't pattern-matching-definition be a closure in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, scope, pattern-matching, closures

Why are these pseudo-Haskell function definitions not accepted?

```
f n = if n<3 then n else g 2 2 1 0 where
    g n a b c = a  -- note that 'n' is a value of the enclosing scope
    g k a b c = g (k+1) (a+2*b+3*c) a b
```

which computes this "exercise-function": `f(n) = n if n<3 else f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) + 3*f(n-3)`

```
fib n = let
     f n a b = b  -- note that 'n' is a value of the enclosing scope
     f k a b = f (k+1) b (a+b)
  in f 1 0 1
```

for computing fibonacci numbers. Of course this works:

```
fib n = let { f k a b = if k==n then b else f (k+1) b (a+b);} in f 1 0 1
```

But in both the example with `where` and the one with `let`, I get

```
Warning: Pattern match(es) are overlapped
```

Why can't I define a function-closure using pattern matching with a value that I get from the enclosing scope?

Is that because the value from the enclosing scope is determined (in general) at runtime and for some reason (What reason?) the compiler cannot orchestrate that?

Comment: It would be possible, but it's a rather fragile construct to have n mean different things in a pattern depending on if it's already bound or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `n` is available to `g` in your example... as long as you don't call one of `g`s parameters `n`.

Answer (score 10):

This is a language design choice: pattern matching can't be done on variables. It avoid tricky brain gymnastic to decide whether or not you pattern match against an existing variable or if  you declare a local variable. Actually, take a look at this example:

Foo.hs:

```
module Foo where

foo: Int = 42
```

Bar.hs:

```
module Bar where

import Foo

bar :: Int -> Bool
bar foo = True
bar _ = False
```

You can't easily guess that `foo` is bound by looking at Bar.hs. Having a syntax where the context is required to decide whether you declare a new variable or use an existing one is misleading.

As a workaround, you can still use guards:

```
f n = if n<3 then n else g 2 2 1 0 where
    g k a _ _ | k == n = a
    g k a b c = g (k+1) (a+2*b+3*c) a b
```

or

```
f n = if n<3 then n else g 2 2 1 0 where
    g k a b c | k == n = a
              | otherwise = g (k+1) (a+2*b+3*c) a b
```

Comment: In the the (long dead) functional language ALFL (from Yale) you could say `#n` instead of `n` to indicate that you wanted to match the value of a variable instead of binding. In Haskell you have to say `... n' ... | n' == n`. Or with `ViewPatterns` you can say `(True <- (== n))`.

Comment: Erlang has this problem.